# sybdb.h causing "two or more data types in declaration specifiers"

Tags: c, compilation, sybase, typedef

I'm compiling a C program which includes sybdb.h and I get the error "two or more data types in declaration specifiers" at the typedef line below (and sybdb.h is a standard file, not one of mine).

```
#if !defined(_WINDEF_) && !defined(_WINDEF_H) && !defined(DOS32X)
typedef int BOOL;
#endif
```

It appears that there is some kind of a conflict with another library I am including, but have no idea what the error means or how to fix it.  Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely *another* header (or your implementation of C itself) has done something like:

```
#define BOOL unsigned char
```

so that your compiler is seeing:

```
typedef int unsigned char;
```

By way of experiment, when I compile the code:

```
#define XYZZY unsigned char
typedef int BOOL;

int main (void) {
    return 0;
}
```

it works fine but, when I change that first line to `#define BOOL unsigned char`, I get the exact same message you see:

```
qq.c:2:17: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
qq.c:2:5: warning: useless type name in empty declaration
```

To confirm this, you can compile only the pre-processor phase to see what that code really looks like to the compiler phase.

This depends on the compiler, of course, `gcc -E` is the option you would use for `gcc`.

Fixing it is another matter. You may well have to change one of the alias types to `BOOL1` or something incredibly ugly like that. That's likely to be a larger change since I imagine it would be used quite a bit.

You *may* be able to get away with simply ensuring both subsystems use the same definition of `BOOL` but it will still take quite a bit of analysis to confirm that this won't have adverse side effects.

To test (and even possibly implement) this fix, you can change the `#if` statement to something like:

```
#ifndef SKIP_BOOL_DEF
    #if !defined(_WINDEF_) && !defined(_WINDEF_H) && !defined(DOS32X)
        typedef int BOOL;
    #endif
#endif
```

and then compile your code with `gcc -DSKIP_BOOL_DEF` (or equivalent) to ensure the `typedef` isn't done. It would then use your (hopefully compatible) system definition.

Comment: That was it - so I added an ifndef to skip this redefinition and it stopped complaining